# Removing [selected] borders in a DetailsView control

Tags: asp.net, css, stylesheet, detailsview

I have a [DetailsView control](http://www.albaassoc.com/events/eventdetails.aspx?eventid=29) which includes several rows that form an address. Ideally I'd like to 'merge' the Address row with the following two rows - essentially removing the borders between them.

I'm guessing that I could use a asp:TemplateField to create an approximate solution (use a single row, but us line breaks in the seconf (data) cell), but I'd rather see if there are any other means along the same lines of my previous styling (using CssClass). Besides, this is a learning exercise as much as anything else.

I've tried giving the Address2 BoundField a class and removing the bottom and top borders via CSS, but it doesn't seem to work. Looking at the HTML, it is assigning the class to a single cell, whereas I think that I need to apply this class to to the whole row. I can't any means of address the full row; I can deal with all rows, either column or just one cell.

Any suggestions?

Code Snippets:

HTML:

```
<h2 class="title">Event Details</h2>
    <div class="entry">
        <form id="frmEvents" runat="server">
            <asp:DetailsView ID="vwEventDetails" runat="server" CssClass="vwEventDetails" FieldHeaderStyle-CssClass="FieldCol" >
                <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Event" DataField="EventName" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="EventName" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date &amp; Time" DataField="EventDate" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="EventDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="Address1" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Address1" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="Address2" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Address2" ItemStyle-CssClass="noBorders" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="Address3" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Address3" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Town" DataField="Town" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Town" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="County" DataField="County" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="County" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Postcode" DataField="Postcode" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Postcode" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Entry Fee" DataField="EventFee" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="EntryFee" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sponsor" DataField="SponsorName" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Sponsor" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="CategoryName" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Category" />
                    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="" DataTextField="" Text="Make A Booking" DataNavigateUrlFields="EventID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="bookevent.aspx?eventid={0}" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.vwEventDetails .FieldCol
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    width: 100px;
}

.vwEventDetails tr td
{
    padding: 0 2em;
}

.noBorders
{
    border-bottom-style:none;
    border-top-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 styles:

```
.noTopBorders { border-top: none; }
.noBottomBorders { border-bottom: none; }
```

I would assign `noTopBorders` to the `HeaderStyle-CssClass` and the `ItemStyle-CssClass` properties of the "Address2" and "Address3" BoundFields.

I would assign `noBottomBorders` to the `HeaderStyle-CssClass` and the `ItemStyle-CssClass` properties of the "Address1" and "Address2" Bound Fields.

Comment: Ken, Thanks but this didn't work either. I could make various changes using your suggest classes, but not remove the borders. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would need to see your page in order to identify why it doesn't work for you.  Your link is currently broken.

Comment: Hmmm... It's up now - not sure when or why it was ever down.

Comment: The page appears correctly in ie7 and chrome, but not in FF.  I would start by removing the border-collapse style on the table, removing the border attribute from the table and using css to apply borders to that table's td attributes.